# Loading iPhone development apps on iPhone using Windows

Tags: iphone, windows

I have an iPhone app prototype and I can't get it on my iPhone from Windows. The application shows up in my iTunes and my phone syncs properly (there is no message) but the app doesn't show up on my phone. (the prototype also has my UDID built in). Are there any other issues that could be happening? Please help!

Comment: What if it is an ad-hoc build? Do ad hoc builds not work on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Use the iPhone Configuration Utility. Make the Distribution Certificate on your Mac (create a signing request, upload to portal, download certificate, install in keychain), then create a Distribution Provisioning Profile in the portal of an Ad-Hoc type, signed with your Distribution Certificate, tied to an App ID and selected devices. After that, Build and Archive a binary (ipa) of your app in Xcode with that Distribution Provisioning Profile, then 'Share' it in the Xcode Organiser. That ipa can now be added to the Configuration Utility in either OS X or Windows and installed on any device that was selected when creating the Ad-Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile.